# access json object and array

Tags: php, json

Here is my JSON data :

```
{
  "Liste_des_produits1": [{
    "Added_Time": "28-Sep-2009 16:35:03",
    "prod_ingredient": "sgsdgds",
    "prod_danger": ["sans danger pour xyz"],
    "prod_odeur": ["Orange"],
    "prod_nom": "ceciestunproduit",
    "prod_certification": ["HE Ã¢â‚¬Â¢ Haute EfficitÃƒÂ©", "Certifier Ecologo", "Contenant recyclable"],
    "prod_photo": "",
    "prod_categorie": ["Corporel"],
    "prod_desc": "gdsg",
    "prod_format": ["10 kg", "20 kg"]
  }, {
    "Added_Time": "28-Sep-2009 16:34:52",
    "prod_ingredient": "dsgdsgdsf",
    "prod_danger": ["Sans danger pour le fausse sceptiques"],
    "prod_odeur": ["Agrumes", "Canneberge"],
    "prod_nom": "jsute un test",
    "prod_certification": ["100% Ãƒâ€°co-technologie", "Certifier Ecologo", "Contenant recyclable"],
    "prod_photo": "",
    "prod_categorie": ["Corporel"],
    "prod_desc": "gsdgsdgsdg",
    "prod_format": ["1 Litre", "10 kg"]
  }]
}
```

In PHP, what is the way to access different values of data?

Like: `prod_ingredient` or `prod_danger`.

I have tried:

```
$prod = $result->{'Liste_des_produits1'};
print_r($prod[0]); // error
```

and

```
$result = json_decode($json);
print_r($result['Liste_des_produits1'].prod_ingredient[1]); // error
```

Comment: Use `var_dump`, `var_export` or `print_r` to see how the return value looks like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert the data to an associative array.

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// extend this concept to access other values
$prod_ingredient = $prod['Liste_des_produits1'][0]['prod_ingredient'];
```

Comment: this code : $json = file_get_contents('http://produits-lemieux.com/json.txt');
$prod = json_decode($json);
$prod_ingredient = $prod['Liste_des_produits1'][0]['prod_ingredient'];
print_r($prod_ingredient);

result in this error = Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/studiot/public_html/test3.php on line 12

Comment: My apologies marc-andre mendard, I should have checked the documentation before answering. I have revised my answer slightly.

Comment: just adding TRUE make the whole thng different... can you explain more, but it work, your rock !

Comment: Passing `true` to `json_encode()` decodes JSON objects as associative arrays rather than PHP objects. I was under the impression this was the default behaviour, and it is more intuitive IMO. In any case, the manual page I linked to explains everything in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_decode](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php)

Then you can access the data as a regular array.

Comment: **@strager:** The OP has been edited since brainfck posted this.