# PHP API echo Array (Bigcommerce)

Tags: php, arrays, api

The 'shipping_address' is displaying an error "Notice: Array to string conversion", I have this line of code:

EDIT -- Removed code snippet and replacing it with the full code connecting to BigCommerce store

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'xxx',
    'username'  => 'xxx',
    'api_key'   => 'xxx'
));
$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();


$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders();
$data = json_decode($shipping_address, true);
foreach ($orders as $orders) {

     echo "<table border='1' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' bordercolor='#000' style='border-bottom:0;'>
        <tr>
        <th width='15%'>Barcode</th>
        <th width='7%'>Order date</th>
        <th width='23%'>Customer details</th>
        <th width='8%'>Phone #</th>
        <th width='22%'>Total</th>
        <th width='15%'>Comments</th>
        <th width='10%'>Signature</th>
        </tr>";


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" $orders->id . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $orders->date_created . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $shipping_address = $orders['shipping_address'][0]['first_name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $orders->phone . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>" . $orders->total_inc_tax . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $orders->customer_message . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

}

?>
```

Comment: `$orders->shipping_addresses` is __array__, not __string__

Comment: **Possible duplicate of [access json object and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497243/access-json-object-and-array)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Array to string conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128656/php-array-to-string-conversion-error)

Comment: use foreach() for $orders->shipping_addresses values

Comment: How would you like to display the shipping_addresses array in the column?

Answer (score 0):

you can't display an array directly, instead, you can display it like this:

```
<td>
<?php foreach($orders->shipping_addresses as $address): ?>
"first_name": <?=$address['first_name']?>
"last_name": <?=$address['last_name']?>
"company": <?=$address['company']?>
"street_1": <?=$address['street_1']?>
"street_2": <?=$address['street_2']?>
"phone": <?=$address['phone']?>
"email": <?=$address['email']?>
<br />
<?php endforeach; ?> 
</td>
```

of course, you should decode json using:

```
 json_decode($json, true);
```

Comment: How can I echo this?

Answer (score 0):

Will you determinate variable `$address` for address above. For example:

```
$address = 'Street1:' . $orders->shipping_addresses['street_1'] . '<br>Street2' . $orders->shipping_addresses['street_2'];
```

Also, you can use this inline

```
echo "<td>" . $orders->shipping_addresses['street_1'] . "</td>";
```

In case `$orders->shipping_addresses` was decoded json.

```
json_decode($shipping_addresses, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want in the column

```
John Doe
Company
Street 1
Street 2
+1234567890
johndoe@example.com
```

Try

```
$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders();
$orders_array = json_decode($orders, true);

echo $orders[0]['shipping_address']['first_name'];
```

Comment: Hi Kenneth, I'm getting undefined index for first_name etc, and variable errors with 'address'

Comment: This line
$data = json_decode($shipping_address, true);
is invalid since you have not declared $shipping_address anywhere